# How to animate rotation of an object in circular array, without the rotation affecting direction of the array itself?

Tags: animation, modifiers

The array modifier uses empty, which is parented to another empty in the centre of the circle. Is it possible to animate all the object rotating inwards/outwards the circle without it affecting the array modifier?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: The rotation inwards/outwards, could it be that you mean rotating the caps itself around an axis while staying in their place in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply parent your objects (the empty used for the array modifier **and the mesh object**) to another empty and rotate this last one.

[image]

Doing so will keep the relative location and rotation of the arrayed mesh and the empty used in this array.

That can also be:

[image]

In this case, hook the mesh to an empty and rotate it. Concerning the array, make sure that it is set on "constant offset" (not relative offset).

[image]

Comment: Hey, i have the same issue, but with the difference that my object is a vertical rectangle multiplied in array for a total of 214 parts on a circumference. Can you explain the procedure for doing this? I can't understand it. what's the procedure?